# Any way to create custom elements in google docs ie like OLE/OpenDoc or mediawiki?

Tags: google-docs-api

Is there any way to embed custom parts into a google doc? I know you can do extensions and format the doc certain ways, but what about something more advanced. What I'm looking for is something closer to semantic media wiki, but with all the awesomeness that is google docs.
for instance to have data inline `[[Property name::property value]]` , but displayed as property value

inline queries like this , which are display/updated as a table

```
{{#ask:
 [[Category:City]]
 [[Located in::Germany]] 
 |?Population 
 |?Area#km² = Size in km²
}}
```

I know the first response, why not use ThisWiki or ThatWiki, and the problem is google docs is better (far better) at formatting, printing, etc which is where most people are comfortable, but several folks would like something more expressive and "computable". Also, we want one system.